# Flash Management in Prefix Controller in Cake PHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I did not find anything about this, so I ask you guys,  
When I create a controller with the command `cake bake` like this:

```
cake bake controller --prefix manager accounts
```

Cake automatically creates a controller and 4 normal functions/َaction in it,  
And in the error management section (known as Flash) there is this line:

```
$this->Manager->error(__('The account could not be deleted. Please, try again.'));
```

In a typical controller it is as follows:

```
$this->Flash->error(__('The account could not be deleted. Please, try again.'));
```

You see, the Flash replaced with Manager and caused an error,
[image]

So I can easily change it with Flash and it works fine, and I also know if I create this path in the prefix folders: `Template \ Manager \ Element \ Flash \ (3 files)` by cake as Default "manager" is used for this prefix, but if I use $this-> Flash! Not from $this>Manager...

My question is that if the cake configures Manager instead of Flash, it must have a program for it, but I can not find a source for it, Does anyone know how I can do this if I want to use Manager exactly as Cake did?

Any tips can be helpful, even a source link
Thanks in advance

Comment: CakePHP, respectively Bake, does not generate such code, the `$this->Flash->error()` line in [**the bake templates**](https://github.com/cakephp/bake/tree/1.12.0/src/Template/Bake/Element/Controller) is hard coded, and it would appear that it always was.

Comment: @ndm You're right man, my cake seems to have a problem. I reinstalled it and this problem did not happen anymore or I hit it with other commands and left the Manager again! Thank you very much for your help: x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of my dear friend "ndm", my problem was found, it seems that my "cakephp" had a problem that mistakenly uses this phrase instead of "Flash". And that was not a definition in this framework.

I reinstalled cakephp and it never happened again, and my attempt to find the cause of this incident was unsuccessful.

reference :
https://github.com/cakephp/bake/tree/1.12.0/src/Template/Bake/Element/Controller